# How do I disable or drop the Price List dependency for Opportunities in Dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: dependencies, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, entity-relationship

It's a pretty ridiculous for Microsoft to assume there will be Products or Price Lists on every Opportunity. They really need to remove this dependency.

For now, I'm creating workflows to auto-set a default pricelist with nothing in it. But it's silly for me to have to do this workaround for every org I deploy.

The overall issue I'm attempting to resolve is the irritating error message/reminder at the top of the record if a Price List isn't provided. If there's another way to eliminate that specific reminder, I'm all ears. If not, is there a way to drop this dependency?

Comment: Why it's ridiculous? What is an opportunity for your company if isn't a prospect to sell a product or a service?

Comment: There are plenty of scenarios where products aren't used IMO. Anyway, you don't need to provide one for Opp do you? The field isn't locked on the form?

Comment: What glosrob said; Service aren't typically line-items that have specific pricing attached. There's a huge difference between POS relationships and enterprise, contractual engagements.

The record can be saved without a Price List. The issue is the irritating error message at the top of the record if one isn't provided. I've updated the question above for greater clarity if there's a way to get rid of that message. However, I still stand on my thoughts about the requirement. It's ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Revenue field on the Opportunity to default to "User Defined" in the solution. As an extra bonus, make it not "Visible by Default" on the Opportunity form.

The warning comes up because the Revenue is set to System Calculated by default, and a price list is required for that.

No client of mine has EVER added Products to Opportunities in CRM, so I a